# How gmail fetches data into page

Tags: javascript, web, gmail, google-chrome-devtools

I'm currently developing a chrome extension for gmail. I want to trigger some actions when user opens an email and grub sender's email address from there. So the idea I came up with is to intercept `XMLHttpRequest.send` via prototype and if this request contains email data then just trigger my events from there. But gmail ain't send any rest request and gets email's body using [the dark force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Force_(Star_Wars)). I'm really stuck into question how googles gets email body and other data to page. I mean the only way new data can appear in the page is via `rest`:

- Form submission
- XMLHttpRequest
- WebSockets

All of those can be inspected via `dev-tools`. So I created a snippet that adds a `DOMSubtreeModified` listener to the `top` of the `document`. And inside of listener I query the body with xpath for email data I'm opening.

E.g. I want to find how gmail fetched data for email `A`. I know that this email contains some specific text like `random text r2d2`. So I just check in my listener whether document contains now nodes with innerText `random text r2d2`. And afterwords I just check `Network` tab for request that were send between clicking on open email button and appearing new text in the page. [Here's the video to understand what I'm talking about.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCWyiRd47HI&feature=youtu.be)

```js
function findEleWithText(text) {
  let parent = document.body;
  let results = [];
  let query = document.evaluate("//*[contains(text()," + text + "')]",
      parent || document,
      null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
  for (let i=0, length=query.snapshotLength; i<length; ++i) {
    results.push(query.snapshotItem(i));
  }
  return results;
}
document.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', e => {
  var e2 = findEleWithText("2:09 p.m.", document.body)
  if (e2.length > 0 ) {
    console.log('e');
  }
})
```

But here's the issue, the data for email appears in the page but `Network` tab shows that no request were made. How is it even possible for data to travel into page? I mean even if request were made from iframe it would be shown in the `Networks` anyway. I also checked if google opens a websocket (ws data isn't shown to `Networks`) - but it doesn't!

Any ideas? Are there ways to fetch data w/o duing REST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that gmail prefetches emails during displaying the list of emails. While opening an email gmail just displays the data from variable it fetched already.